# Write StringIO to Tempfile

Tags: ruby, io

I am trying in ruby to read image from *url* and than save it to `Tempfile` to be later processed.

```
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Robie_House.jpg'
file = Tempfile.new(['temp','.jpg'])
stringIo = open(url)
# this is part I am confused about how to save StringIO to temp file?
file.write stringIo
```

This does not work that is resulting `temp.jpg` is not valid image. Not sure how to proceed with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're super close:

```
file.binmode
file.write stringIo.read
```

`open(url)` is just opening the stream for reading. It doesn't actually read the data until you call `.read` on it (which you can then pass in to `file.write`).

Comment: Thank you, super close hehe love that. Also I was missing `file.binmode` in case somebody has similar issue.

Comment: thnx for the file.binmode!!

Answer (score 4):

You could also create your tempfile with the correct encoding, like so:

> file = Tempfile.new(['temp','.jpg'], :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')

This is the same as setting the file to binmode.